# alternative to memcached

Tags: cache, memory, memcached

I'm asking this to benefit others. I was reading thehackernews.com and noticed that memcached (a back-end for webservers that helps users produce speedier websites) has flaws to the point where sensitive information could be leaked into the wrong party.

Here's the article:

http://thehackernews.com/2016/11/memcached-hacking.html

Since this back-end is not so secure, what would you recommend as a better back-end to help speed up websites that is trustworthy and free?

Comment: An exploit was discovered and patched within 2 days. This is not a good reason to switch to alternative software, especially as your memcache server should not be remotely accessible in the first place.